# why the compress function in zlib is different between windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, compression, zlib

With the same zlib version 1.2.11 and the same code:

```
char * msg = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
unsigned char buf[1024]={0};
unsigned long buf_len=1024;
FILE *f;
int ret = compress(buf,&buf_len,(const Bytef*)msg,strlen(msg));
printf("ret:%d,%.*s\n",ret,buf_len,buf);
f = fopen("output.txt","wb");
if(f)
{
    fwrite(buf,buf_len,1,f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

the windows's output is:
78 9C 33 30 00 02 00 02 D5 00 F1

the linux's output is：
00 00 00 00 00 02 00 02 D5 00 F1

Why they do not have the same output?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in both cases. The first one is at least a valid zlib stream, but for some reason it codes five "0" digits instead of the 40 supplied. The second one apparently also had the same problem as the first, *plus* it had the first four bytes zeroed out somehow, so it is not even a valid zlib stream.

When I run the code (adding in `(int)` before the `buf_len` in the `printf`, just to avoid warnings), I get a proper zlib stream that codes all 40 "0" digits. I ran it on both Linux and Darwin (macOS) with no problem.